# What free video editor is best to stabilize video and fix choppy ones?

Tags: video-editor, post-production, stabilisation, freeware

I shoot at 30 fps using iPhone 11 Pro and a gimbal (I can't upgrade for now). I still have some stability issues and the video gets a little choppy. So what is the best FOSS video editor to solve this cos there're just toooo many of them - Resolve, Shotcut, Olive, Blender, etc.

I currently use Filmora and I wanna change. So, something not too complicated is appreciated. Thx guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve has pretty good [stabilisation tools](https://www.learncolorgrading.com/the-3-different-modes-of-stabilization-in-davinci-resolve/). Blender is more about 3D work and has a steeper learning curve in my opinion. Haven't used the other two.